# grunt rpm create a symlink

Tags: gruntjs, symlink, rpm, rpmbuild

I have this grunt file that creates a rpm package for me, how can I create a symlink like this for an example:

> link("/usr/local/bin/tams-cli", "/opt/tams-cli/tams-cli.js")

Have not been able to to find that, here below is my source code.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('./package.json'),
    easy_rpm: {
      options: {
        buildArch,
        rpmDestination: './built/',
      },
      release: {
        files: [
          {
            src: ['node_modules/**/*',
              'js/**/*',
              'cfg/*',
              'package.json',
              'readme.md',
            ],
            dest: '/opt/tams-cli',
          },
          {
            src: 'tams-cli.js',
            dest: '/opt/tams-cli',
            mode: 0550,
          }
        ],
        excludeFiles: [
          'tmp-*',
          './built',
        ],
      },
    },
```

Comment: Is it just one symlink you need to create, or multiple? Should the symlink(s) be created _before_ running your `easy_rpm` task or _after_?

Comment: @RobC I'ts just one symlink, I really don't have any preference wheather it should be created before or after, just what is easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the symlink after the rpm package is installed utilize the [`postInstallScript`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-easy-rpm#postinstallscript) option in your `easy_rpm` task. The description for the `postInstallScript` reads:

> **postInstallScript**
>
> `Array<String>`
>
> An array of commands to be executed after the installation. Each element in the array represents a command.

In the `Gruntfile.js` excerpt below it utilizes the [`ln`](https://ss64.com/bash/ln.html) command to create the symlink using the additional two options:

- `-s` to make a symbolic link instead of a hard link.
- `-f` to remove existing destination files if they exist already.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  // ...
  easy_rpm: {
    options: {
      postInstallScript: ['ln -s -f /opt/tams-cli/tams-cli.js /usr/local/bin/tams-cli'],
      // ..
    },
    // ...
  },
  // ...
});
```

Comment: thanks for an excellent answare, I'm testing solution A. I got the following error:
`Files: [no src] -> /usr/local/bin/tams-cl
Options: overwrite=false, force=false
Warning: Path must be a string. Received undefined Use --force to continue.`
Does this path have to exist on my locall machine to work?
This is a configuration for a remote system, which has different folder structure than my local machine.

Comment: My desired outcome is; when the rpm package is installed on a remote machine, then the symlink metntioned gets created. Therefore I'm simulating those paths, but they do not exsists on my locall machine. Are we maybe misunderstanding what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: `postInstallScript: ['ln -s /opt/tams-cli/tams-cli.js /usr/local/bin/tams-cli']`
this did the trickt, really apprciate your help and patience, sorry for not being explict enough in explaning the issue.

Comment: No worries - together we eventually got the required solution. Perhaps I hadn't had enough coffee ;)

Comment: Weill it's Friday, so I suggest skip the coffee and let's move straight to beer ;)